# sharepoint page changes are visible on admin site(authoring site) but no changes are affected in public facing sites 

Tags: sharepoint-designer

i have made changes to a page in sharepoint designer .
I am able to see the page with the changes made by me in authoring site but i am unable to find the same changes on the Public facing internet site .
can anybody help me with this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked-in, published and approved the page after changing it? Additionally: are you using Content Deployment to publish content? If so, did you published the content to the public website?

Comment: ya i have checked in the page after changing it .
Also i have approved the page .
I have just made changes to size of a image , which can be seen in my administrative site but same changes are not getting affected in the public site .

Comment: Do you have cache enabled for the public website?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the page back in?

Comment: Some pages have to be published also.

Comment: ya i have checked in the page so thats why i am able to find the changes in administrative site . but no idea abt why it isnt there in public site :(